# Filling black color outside of rectangle area on image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

Use OpenCV 3.2

Need filling sides of image with black color.

I create rect objects for each party. And simple draw it on the picture. But the solution seems cumbersome.

```
// Border 100 px
cv::Rect top_rect(0, 0, img.size().width, 100)
...
cv::rectangle(img, top_rect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);
cv::rectangle(img, bot_rect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);
cv::rectangle(img, left_rect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);
cv::rectangle(img, right_rect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);
```

I found solutions like:

```
Rect roi(100, 100, 600, 400);
Mat result_img = img(roi);
```

But this solution changes the size of image.
`copyMakeBorder` - is also resizes.
**I need to: take an area outside the rectangle and fill it with black color.**
The image dimensions should remain the same.

Is there a ready-made function in OpenCV?

Comment: `copyMakeBorder` should maintain the original image size if you give it the proper border widths... what values did you use?

Comment: "I found solutions" -- maybe time to think and come up with one ;) | Using a ROI is the right way to go. Unfortunately you seem to have stopped half-way there. Not only do you have to extract a smaller rectangle from the input image, you also have to copy the contents into a region of a black canvas located at the same position. So far you only have the smaller extracted region, so it's obviously not the same size as the input image.

Comment: I thought about it, but the number of steps would have turned out to be the same as just drawing the areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method that you can use is to copy the image using a mask:

```
inputMat.copyTo(outputMat, maskMat);
```

`maskMat` is a `cv::Mat` that has the same size of the image, but is binary. The ROI should contain pixel values of 1, and the rest should be 0.

Comment: Thank you. It even allows you to create a mask from an external image.